# Github Pages reloads only when switched between tabs

Tags: javascript, github, reload, github-pages

I've been building a simple JavaScript pong game for school using just html canvas. When one of the players' scores reaches 5, the page is supposed to reload and start from scratch. For this I've tried:

```
document.location.reload();
window.location.reload(true);
```

When I test it locally, everything works great. But when I upload and access through the website, it takes ~40 seconds to proceed.
[Website](https://makskoseda.github.io/games/pong)
[Source code](https://github.com/MaksKoseda/makskoseda.github.io/tree/master/games/pong)

EDIT:
Reloading is instant when I switch between tabs in my browser. FYI I use Chrome, but I've tried Firefox and it's the same. Is this GP's fault? Is there a workaround for it? Help much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you reloading the whole page? Could you just reset the score to 0?

Comment: I've tried it and it's a little more complex than that. I'll try to figure it out, but this shouldn't have happened in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `function draw() {` is running continuously due to `setInterval(draw, 10);`, which is nearly blocking. Try clearing the interval once the end is reached:

```
const drawInterval = setInterval(draw, 10);
function draw() {
  if (end1 || end2) clearInterval(drawInterval);
```

It would be far better to just reset the JS rather than reload, though.